# Angular / Firebase - Return the Key and the Value from Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire

I am working on an Angular project and following some tutorial managed to get some data from the firebase database.

Here is the code that gets the values

```
<ul>
<li class="text" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
  {{item.$value}}
</li>
</ul>
```

My question is ... I am getting the values but I want to get the names too (or keys, if that's the name).

For example the data looks like this:

```
items
 name: car,
 value: ford
```

This code:

```
<ul>
  <li class="text" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    {{item.$value}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the JS code:

```
export class AppComponent {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  snippets: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('/items');
  }
}
```

will only return the value.

How do I get both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the angularfire2 library just pass the `preserveSnapshot` parameter

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>{{key | async}}</h1>
    <h1>{{value | async}}</h1>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  key: any;
  value: any;
    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.items = db.list('/items', { preserveSnapshot: true });
    this.items
      .subscribe(snapshots => {
        snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
          this.key = snapshot.key;
          this.value = snapshot.val()
        });
      })}

}
```

for more info visit the official docs [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/tree/master/docs)

Comment: This is the current code: export class AppComponent {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  snippets: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('/items');
  }
}

Comment: @dj2017 I have edited my answer to make it more clear for you so I wrote the full component to make you better understand it